# Ways to drop/manage user's sessions in case that sessions are stored in default php session storage?

Tags: php

Are there any ways to drop user sessions when sessions are stored in default php session storage?

For example, I'm website admin and I want to ban logged user. User authentification status is stored in session. I'm deleting user row from database, but user is still logged and all nessesary authentification information is also stored in session. I need to drop/modify session.

Possible ways:

- load user's row from DB on every request
- create file, saying to delete user's session and check this file existence on every request
- crete file in /dev/shm (very fast checking), but file will be removed when rebooted
- store sessions in DB (overhead for my project)
- store sessions in nosql (redis, memcachedb) (overhead for my project)

Any elegant ways except storing user's sessions in database or nosql data storages?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow but why not use session_destroy() - or just unsetting the logged in variable used to check login status?

Comment: @jtheman he's talking about an admin in say an admin panel disabling a user.  Not the user doing something that disables his account and destroys his session.

Comment: default php session store is file-based. To kill a session externally, you need to know the ID of the session, then delete the corresponding session file (usually `sess_XXX` where xxx is the session id). Probably 5 lines of code (at most) in the "ban the user" script could accomplish this, even just `unlink(session_save_path() . "/sess_$bannedID")` could do.

Comment: From what I understand, sessions should only be accessed by the user that created them.  Therefore you're stuck with loading user's row (or a small part of that information) on every request.  But I'm no expert, sorry.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.php  For the

Comment: @Ray ok now I get it. Yes save the session id in db then to ban the user not just delete the users session in db. But also the session file...

Comment: every X seconds/minutes, while loading user's session on yet-another-request (probably with session_load()) you could check this users ID from the session against the DB user entry, and if there is no DB entry - destroy his session... So after X seconds/minutes since deleting a user on DB you would force session destroy

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to store the session in the database.  That, to me is like storing an unencripted password, anyone that has access to the session, has access to your account

Comment: @Kubee - so far DB is good protected - its good as saving session on file or even better (e.g. with multiple webservers)

Comment: @Laimoncijus Still, it happens: http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/11/10/steam-database-hacked-encrypted-credit-card-information-and-passwords-compromised/

Comment: @Kubee there is always good chance that you can get hacked - but the same could also happen to a webserver too, where session files and/or sources are stored...

Comment: @Laimoncijus Very true, but exposing yourself more doesn't help (now there are 2 points of failure).  Of course, you CAN be too careful and I think I'm being a little too 'nit picky'.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do this is to delete the session record.  If it's a file, delete the session file.  If session is stored in a DB or memcache delete it there.  The tough question is how to find the session id and if one even exists for a user.

If it's a file an you store the email or user id in it, you could look for that file. Session storage in DB should be easy to query.  Not sure how you'd do it in memcache.

If you don't regenerate sessions on each request, you could always set the session_id on session creation to something unique to a user--be careful if you don't use SSL you might open a way to hijack sessions if the unique key you use is easy to guess (like a user_id).  You could then store the users session id once in the DB with the user record when they log in.